# Chrome Extension DOMContentLoaded Not Firing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Right now I am trying to get the following code to run, but the console never logs 'added', only 'started'.

```
var addWebsiteAddress;
console.log('started');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  console.log('added');
  addWebsiteAddress = document.forms["addWebsiteAddress"];
  addWebsiteAddress.addEventListener('submit', addWebsite);
```

I've placed it in the HTML file as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js" async></script>
    <title>Add a website to block</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="addWebsiteForm">
    Website Address: <input type="text" id="websiteAddress"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Website">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? DOMContentLoaded never seems to fire as I am unable to register the submit event as well.

Comment: What happens if you take out `async`?

Comment: Oh, it works. I don't understand why though - I thought async would just run the script separately from the loading of the web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit here is `async` attribute you're using.

Normally, when adding the `<script>` tag to the DOM, the browser will pause parsing the page to execute the script. With `async`, this is not guaranteed to be the case. It can be executed at an arbitrary point.

Your page is *very* small. Browser parses it nearly instantly and the event is fired before it "remembers" to execute your script - and as such it's not received by your script.

The idea behind `async` is not to stumble with the page loading as the script itself is loading. Since the resources in a Chrome extension are all local, loading times are not a factor, and as such you should not use it, opting for a more predictable program flow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you set **"run_at": "document_end"** in **manifest.json**.
Change **"run_at": "document_end"** to **"run_at": "document_start"**.
It works! I tried!